# vim キーマップの取り消しに関して

Tags: vim

すみません、検索しても出てこなかったので質問させていただきます。
補完機能をvimに実装するため、以下コマンドを実行したのですが、この補完機能を取り消したいです。
（誤って登録してしまいました。）

＜vimコマンド＞
・inoremap {  "zdi^V{} "zdi^V{}}

上記補完機能を取り消しする場合にはどのコマンドを入れればよろしいでしょうか。
教えていただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キーマッピングの削除であれば、この場合挿入モードの `{` に割り当てているので、以下のようにします。

```
iunmap {
```

また、Vim のキーマッピングは起動毎に初期化されるので、設定ファイル `.vimrc` にマッピングを書かなければ、再起動でも元に戻ります。

Comment: 有難う御座います。設定ファイルvimrcを作るためググりながらやっているのですが、これはhomeフォルダに移動し、vimrcを作成、及び必要な設定をsetでセッティングしていく形で正しいでしょうか。

Comment: vimrc に関して言えば概ねその認識で合っています。ただし恐らくこの質問とは直接は関係ないかと思います。

Comment: 有難う御座います。無事ファイルを作成しvimを閉じても対応されるようになりました。

Comment: @Mr.MeganeBoy 解決したならこの回答を承認することができます ([自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) をご覧ください）．元の問題が解決しているという指標にもなりますのでぜひどうぞ．